# How to connect to SQL Server in windows authentication mode from Java EE Spring application?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, windows-authentication

I want to connect my Java EE web application to SQL Server database in windows authentication mode. I have two **Spring.xml** file, **Spring-Datasource.xml** and **Spring-Customer.xml** that both of them are imported in **Spring-Module.xml**. this my Spring-Datasource.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>        
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Spring;" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is my Main class:

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.mkyong.customer.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context;

            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

            CustomerDAO customerDAO = (CustomerDAO) context.getBean("customerDAO");
            Customer customer;
            customer = new Customer("mkyong", 28);
            customerDAO.insert(customer);

            Customer customer1 = customerDAO.findByCustomerId(1);
            System.out.println(customer1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("********************************************");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("********************************************");
        }
    }
}
```

But i always get this error:

`********************************************
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
********************************************`

How can i solve that?

NOTE:
**I'm beginner in Java**

Comment: look this:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216283/tomcat-java-sql-server-2008-r2-cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-con



    

it may be usefull

Comment: Voting this down as question is different than actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do  you have JDBC driver library in your class path.? For j2ee it should be in the lib folder.

Comment: Yeah, see these screen shots http://bayanbox.ir/id/94123013334564624?view and http://bayanbox.ir/id/3072569240515208745?view