# Tomcat, MySQL -> Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, driver, tomcat8

I know this looks like a repeat question but have tried all posts in stackoverflow and other forums but to no avail.

Apache Tomcat 8.0.32
Amazon RDS running MySQL 5.6
Running tomcat on EC2 windows server

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
...
  <resource-ref>
    <description>datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/bbDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  </resource-ref>
...
</web-app>
```

Context.xml sitting in the META-INF folder of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/ch">
   <Resource name="jdbc/bbDataSource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="********"
        password="********"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://*url*:3306/x?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
 </Context>
```

Creating the datasource in a ServletContextListener

```
try {
        dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/bbDataSource");
        mLogger.log(Level.CONFIG, "Startup - AppContextServletListener - contextInitialized - Created dataSource object: {0}", dataSource);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("dataSource", dataSource);
}
```

No issues during startup.
While accessing the dataSource tomcat throws the above error.
And the jar file is sitting in the lib folder of tomcat (I doubt this is the problem since I'm also using hibernate in the same application and it is able to access the DB without any issues).

Also I noted the following: $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost does not have the 'ch.xml' -> Tried copying the context.xml and renaming to 'ch.xml' there but to no avail.

server.xml -> Under the host node

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="/ch" docBase="ch"></Context>
        <Context path="/ch/asdasd" docBase="C:\\xasdasd\\asdasd">   </Context>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat, Java & SQL Server 2008 R2: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216283/tomcat-java-sql-server-2008-r2-cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-con)

Comment: not really -> that question the 'server.xml' has the resource declaration/definition. In this case the 'context.xml' has it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I see a lot of similar problems under "related" that all come down to wrong name or wrong place of config; you might want to look through those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

In Server.xml added the Resource line under context
Wonder why it needs to be defined twice? Any clues?

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
     <Context path="/ch" docBase="ch">
        <Resource name="jdbc/bbDataSource"
             auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource"
             username="********"
             password="********"
             driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://x:3306/x?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
     </Context>
 </Host>
```